# bloquear acesso com Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Beleza, na configuração que fiz não estou conseguindo bloquear o acesso as paginas que ficam dentro de outra pasta dentro da minha pasta **views**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso eu estou tentando bloquear o acesso a tudo que tem dentro da pasta **controle**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha configuração está dessa forma e pelo visto está tudo certo. Precisa ser configurado em outro lugar também?

Comment: Amigo, você adicionou nos controllers que retornam essas páginas alguma anotação para restringir o acesso?

Comment: Não adicionei nenhuma anotação. Minha ideia era fazer toda a configuração no método configure.